# python regex - what does - (dash) mean

Tags: python, regex

I know it can denote range, but for example here `[-.\d]` seems like this means decimal number. What does dash symbol in front of the regex mean?
Also, why apart from `[]`, are there `()` around them? What do the `()` mean?

Comment: [-.\d] in a regex context is the set of the characters '-', '.' and digits 0-9. \d indicates digits in a regex.

Comment: I don't think it is mentioned in the current answers, but inside of a character class (square brackets) a dash can also specify a range.  For example `[a-d]` would match an `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`.  The `-` needs to be the first character (as it is in your example) to mean "match a literal `-` character".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[-.\d]` finds *one character that is either* (`[]`) a dash (`-`), a period (`.`) or a number (`\d`).

The parentheses around mean *grouping*, so that the matched value can later be accessed using the `group()` method of the `Match` object.

See also the [documentation of the `re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Answer (score 6):

The `-` doesn't mean anything special here, it is literally matching a dash (probably looking for dash used as a minus sign). The `.` is also literal -- it will match a dot (probably used for a decimal point). The `\d` will match any number (0-9). If you add a `*` or `+` multiplier to the end of the example you give it will match any number: positive, negative, or floating point.

The () parentheses that are used mark the start and end of a group and the contents of a group can be retrieved after a match has been performed.

See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html for more information.

Comment: Well what are the [] for, then, if () denotes a group?

Comment: The [] brackets are used to create an expression that will match one of anything inside of it. For example `[abc]` will match `a` OR `b` OR `c`. Whereas `abc` will only match the three consecutive characters `abc`.

Comment: so ([abc]) is equivalent to (a|b|b)?

Comment: Sort of, although `|` can be used to OR entire regular expressions, whereas `[]` is only used to build a set of individual characters that can match.

Comment: You should really go read the provided links... try clicking on it and  do a research (ctrl+f) for [] on the page. I swear it does not hurt your fingers.

Answer (score 3):

It means "dash." They probably expect some negative numbers (i.e. -0.5). The `()` means that it is capturing the matches.

Comment: What do you mean by capturing? And how is the decimal point encoded here? Seems like the . there is the special character. (dot) How does it work when you have some digits, then decimal point, then some more digits?

Comment: between [ and ], all special characters are escaped. So if you see: ([-.\d]+), it may mean "find any number (integer, float, negative, etc) and store it somewhere for reuse".

Answer (score 0):

remember that [] it represent a character class, every thing under it is going to be considers as the characters which can present in string, (unless you escape it within character class as you do with \d+), e.g. `[\d-+]+` now in this case the - and + inside [] are just simply the symbol, the + which is outside in character class is now regex repeating symbol.

Comment: That's not a valid python regex. Either you put the dash at the beginning or end, or you use it to indicate a range.

Answer (score 0):

From the [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

> If - is escaped (e.g. [a-z]) or if it’s placed as the first or last
> character (e.g. [-a] or [a-]), it will match a literal '-'.